# Adding UI Listview to my parallel process slows things down considerably

Tags: winforms, listview, task-parallel-library

I am saving more than 100000 files in the background and all is good fast etc...I am using the tpl library and really makes threading easier.

My problem:
Been asked to add some UI to it for a user point of view.
I now have 2 listviews

1. "lvwInProcess" lists all the files in process
2. "lvwSaved" list all the files that have been saved

I cannot use "AddRange" as I am updating one at a time but the adding and removing of an item slowes me down 1000 times

The following is some simplified test code to give you an idea

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        var parOpts = new ParallelOptions();
        string[] files = GetFiles();
        parOpts.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                            {
                                                Parallel.ForEach(files, parOpts, (file, loopState) =>
                                                {
                                                    count = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
                                                    SaveFile(file, count);

                                                });
                                            });
    }

    private void SaveFile(string file, int count)
    {           
        // FileProcess.Save(file);

        //update listview but removing the file
        // from the processing listview and add to the Saved listview

        var item = new ListViewItem(Path.GetFileName(file));
        lvwInProcess.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => lvwInProcess.Items.Add(item)));
        lvwSaved.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => lvwSaved.Items.Remove(item)));
        lvwInProcess.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => lvwProcessing.Refresh()));
        lvwSaved.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => lvwSaved.Refresh()));
    }
```

Cannot use VirtualListView as I am adding and removing
Should I use a different control?

Can the above be improved?
How would you do it?

Comment: Are you really displaying 100 000 items to the user? That doesn't make any sense. No user is going to go though a list that big.

Comment: @svick true.You are right.They want to see some sort of update progress and at the beginning I had a simple progress bar and a couple of labels eg "saved 3 of 3434 etc..." that in my eyes was good as no user would be interested in viewing 10000 however when your boss tell you something and you tell the opposite and then they tell " do it" what do you do? tell them f..off no i cant unfortunately

Comment: Have you asked your boss “Why?”?

Comment: Do you have 2 listviews or 4 listviews?  I see in your SaveFile method, lvwInProcess, lvwSaved, lvwProcessing, lvwPrevalidate.  What is the difference?

Comment: @Scott that was an error.2 listviews I was trying something

Comment: @User231465 how much is "considerably"? I have tested your code in WPF and the whole thing without the ListViews takes 50 seconds and with the ListViews 2:50 minutes. It's a significant slowdown, but it could be acceptable for such a scenario.

Comment: @HighCore thanks for your time and test in wpf.I have given up on UI and I will explain that is not worth it if performance is the priority,thanks

Comment: any final solution with full source code working about it?

Answer (score 0):

With so many items in your ListViews, I would certainly use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate around the Add/Refresh methods.  This will reduce some of the rendering time of the UI.  Also is it possible to use BeginInvoke() to asynchronously update the UI.

Comment: I thought about begin and update but didnt think for 1 item at a time would make any difference. How would use beginInvoke in this scenarion